# One address table for many types of addresses

Tags: database-design, database-agnostic

I have an application where I have to store adresses of multiple types of location.

For example, my app requires addresses of people, hotels and event venues.

Should I create separate tables for different type of addresses having same fields? or Should I add an additional field telling what is the type of address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless the attributes between the different types are totally different (which I doubt), go for the second option and store the address type in a column of the address table.

Comment: I have two different tables and both need an address. Is it okay if I enter foreign key to address table from both the tables above?

Comment: @codecool: that's perfectly fine.